# How to know which user agent is hitting my server?

Tags: linux

If I do

```
netstat -n|grep :80|cut -c 45-|cut -f 1 -d ':'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|more
```

I will get which ip is hitting my server

What should I do to get which user agent is visiting my server?

Comment: Do you have something (presumably an http server) configured on port 80? If so which one? You want to look at the servers logs.

Comment: At the kernel level all that's known is the addresses at the ends of the TCP connection.  For more detail you need information from the application (on port 80, you're probably running an HTTP server, most of which have logs with that kind of info).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CentOS and Apache, you can use:

```
cut -f6 -d\" /var/log/httpd/access_log
```